# Secured configuration for Nginx / PHP with static files

Tags: php, security, nginx, multisite

First of all, I'm not a sysadmin, I'm doing this to better understand how it works behind the scenes.

I have a dedicated server **without** virtual machine: Debian 12, Nginx and PHP8.
I want to install multiple websites perfectly sealed between them.

Static files are not always inside a specific folder like static or assets. (Hello Wordpress)

For PHP files, no problem, I create a PHP pool for each website. But, how I do the same for static files? (Am I paranoid with it?)

If I am paranoid, how to simply run this? www-data for every files and target php files with my specific user? Which user go in which group? I am suspicious about groups and cascading rights.

Do I need to explore a solution like Docker?

Comment: HTML doesn't need a pool as it is served directly, just like images. Personally, I like to have one user per logical Nginx site. So if I have "a.example.com" and "b.example.com", I'd have "user-a" and "user-b". Then, regardless of PHP, HTML or anything else, that user would own the files, and I'd also have a PHP pool owned by that user, with a shared group (usually www-data). This setup should "seal" as long as you don't mess with permissions too much.